# Putting different custom cell types in a tableview

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I've been having problems trying to populate a single tableview with different custom cell types. I have tried to remove all the irrelevant parts of the code. I may have many follow up questions but in the dequereusablecell statement (in the cellforrow function), i am not able to downcast the cell to the types FilterTableViewCell or FilterTableViewCell2 stored in the array cellTypes
. I get the error "Array types are now written with the brackets around the element type"...it thinks im trying to downcast to an array type as opposed to the cell type in the given index of the array cellTypes. I hope that's clear.

I have also tried putting one dequereusablecell statement in each case of the switch statement but i get errors in other parts of my code. It basically treats FIlterTableViewCell and FilterTableViewCell2 as if they're the baseclass type (UITableViewCell) and it therefore can't access properties within these two subclasses. I hope that's kind of clear. but if you notice anything at all problematic in my other parts of my code (especially how i'm using arrays) let me know.

Code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FilterViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate,UITextViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    let properties = ["Diet","Body Type","Looking For","Ethnicity"]
    var values:NSArray!
    let dietOpts:NSArray = ["Vegan","Plant-based","Vegetarian","Meat Eater"]
    let bodytypeOpts:NSArray = ["Muscular","Athletic","Lean","Husky","Chubby","Large","Fat"]
    let lookingforOpts:NSArray = ["Friends","Dates","Chat","Networking","Relationship","Right Now"]
    let ethnicityOpts:NSArray = ["Hispanic/Latino","Black","White","Middle Eastern","South Asian","Asian","Native American","Pacific Islander"]

    var userFilterTable : UITableView!

    var cellTypes = [FilterTableViewCell.self,FilterTableViewCell.self,FilterTableViewCell2.self,FilterTableViewCell2.self]
    var reminderCells = [FilterTableViewCell(),FilterTableViewCell(),FilterTableViewCell2(),FilterTableViewCell2()]
    let cellIDs = ["cellId","cellId","cellId2","cellId2"]
    var toolBar : UIToolbar!
    var i:Int!
    var myUIPicker = UIPickerView()
    var multiplePicker = MultiplePicker()
    var myValues: NSArray!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        let barHeight: CGFloat = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
        let displayWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width
        let displayHeight: CGFloat = self.view.frame.height
        userFilterTable = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: barHeight, width: displayWidth, height: displayHeight - barHeight))

        userFilterTable.register(FilterTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
        userFilterTable.register(FilterTableViewCell2.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId2")

        userFilterTable.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        userFilterTable.isScrollEnabled = false
        userFilterTable.delegate = self
        userFilterTable.dataSource = self
        userFilterTable.rowHeight = 40

        self.userFilterTable.reloadData()
        self.view.addSubview(userFilterTable)
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton!){
        print("Button tapped")
    }

    func generalPicker(){
        myUIPicker.becomeFirstResponder()
        self.myUIPicker.delegate = self
        self.myUIPicker.dataSource = self
    }

    @objc func donePicker() {
        reminderCells[i].valueTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func doMultiplePicker(){
        multiplePicker.becomeFirstResponder()
        //multiplePicker.delegate = self
        //multiplePicker.dataSource = self

        reminderCells[i].valueTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
    }

    @objc func donePicker2() {
        reminderCells[i].valueTextField.text = multiplePicker.str
        reminderCells[i].valueTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        reminderCells[indexPath.row].valueTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

        i = indexPath.row
        print(properties[indexPath.item]) //print("Diet")
        switch properties[indexPath.item] {
        case "Diet":
            myValues = dietOpts
            generalPicker()
        case "BodyType":
            myValues = bodytypeOpts
            generalPicker()
        case "Looking For":
            myValues = lookingforOpts
            generalPicker()
        case "Ethnicity":
            myValues = bodytypeOpts
            doMultiplePicker()
        default:
            print("Some other character")
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // retuen no of rows in sections
        return properties.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        print(indexPath.row)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIDs[indexPath.row], for: indexPath) as! cellTypes[indexPath.row]

        switch properties[indexPath.item]{
            case "Diet","Body Type":
                let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(donePicker))
                toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
                cell.valueTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
                cell.valueTextField.inputView = myUIPicker
            case "Looking For","Ethnicity":
                multiplePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 300)
                multiplePicker.myValues = ethnicityOpts as! [String]
                let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(donePicker2))
                toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
                cell.valueTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
                cell.valueTextField.inputView = multiplePicker
            default:
                print("default")

        }
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.property.text = properties[indexPath.item]
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cell.valueTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cell.valueTextField.delegate = self
        cell.valueTextField.tag = indexPath.item
        toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
        reminderCells[indexPath.item] = cell
        return cell
    }

    // data method to return the number of column shown in the picker.
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // data method to return the number of row shown in the picker.
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        print(myValues.count)
        return myValues.count
    }

    // delegate method to return the value shown in the picker
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return myValues[row] as? String
    }

    // delegate method called when the row was selected.
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        reminderCells[i].valueTextField.text = myValues[row] as? String
    }
}
```

Edit Made to cellForRowAt after Matt's response (this time i specify the type at compile time):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch properties[indexPath.item]{
        case "Diet","Body Type":
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIDs[indexPath.row], for: indexPath) as! FilterTableViewCell
            let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(donePicker))
            toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
            cell.valueTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
            cell.valueTextField.inputView = myUIPicker

            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            cell.property.text = properties[indexPath.item]
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.valueTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.valueTextField.delegate = self
            cell.valueTextField.tag = indexPath.item
            toolBar = UIToolbar()
            toolBar.sizeToFit()
            reminderCells[indexPath.item] = cell
            return cell
        case "Looking For","Ethnicity":
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIDs[indexPath.row], for: indexPath) as! FilterTableViewCell2
            multiplePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 300)
            multiplePicker.myValues = ethnicityOpts as! [String]
            let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(donePicker2))
            toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
            cell.valueTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
            cell.valueTextField.inputView = multiplePicker

            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            cell.property.text = properties[indexPath.item]
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.valueTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.valueTextField.delegate = self
            cell.valueTextField.tag = indexPath.item
            toolBar = UIToolbar()
            toolBar.sizeToFit()
            reminderCells[indexPath.item] = cell
            return cell
        default:
            print("default")

    }
```

Comment: Yes i'm getting compile errors in other parts of the code and they all involve references to reminderCells[indexPath.row]...it treats it as a baseclass type (UITableViewCell) and not the custom types (the FilterTableViewCell's)...i can't even run the code yet. i need to fix the "dequereusablecell' statement in the cellforrowat tableview function:          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIDs[indexPath.row], for: indexPath) as! cellTypes[indexPath.row]... the speific error i get for this line is "Array types are now written with the brackets around the element type"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This idea from your `dequeue` call in `cellForRowAt` is ingenious and natural-seeming, but illegal:

```
as! cellTypes[indexPath.row]
```

Swift won't let you cast (`as!`) to a type that is not specified until runtime. It's a static language, not a dynamic language. The type must be a *literal* type specified at compile time.

You'll just have to split your `cellForRowAt` implementation into two completely separate switch cases, one for rows 0 and 1, and one for rows 2 and 3, and do a different `dequeue` for each one, each one declaring and specifying its own local `cell` variable with a cast `as! FilterTableViewCell` or `as! FilterTableViewCell2` *literally* — and proceeding from there, *separately*, within each case.

You cannot unify the two cases as your elegant-looking code attempts to do, because only in a context where `cell` is typed *literally* as FilterTableViewCell or FilterTableViewCell2 can you access the properties belonging to the respective type.

As for this expression:

```
var reminderCells = [FilterTableViewCell(),FilterTableViewCell(),
                     FilterTableViewCell2(),FilterTableViewCell2()]
```

...the problem here is that Swift can only infer that this must be an array of UITableViewCell, which has no FilterTableViewCell properties.

You could work around this by defining a third type, e.g. FilterTableViewCellParent, to act as a common superclass for FilterTableViewCell and FilterTableViewCell2, and giving *it* their common properties which they can both inherit; `reminderCells` could then be an array of FilterTableViewCellParent and you'd be able to access the properties through an element of it. (Or of course you could make FilterTableViewCell the superclass of FilterTableViewCell2 or *vice versa*, and thus do it with just two types.)

But personally I think you should abandon your attempts to be "elegant" and just do everything completely separately in the two cases of the switch, even at the cost of some repetition. Sometimes one must just program the same way Superman gets into his pants; he may be Superman but he still has to get into one leg at a time.

Comment: hey matt. understood. i edited my post and I added my new version of the cellForRowAt function code.  Ok  now the errors i get now involve any place in my code that references reminderCells[i] or reminderCells[indexPath.row]...the error: "value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'valueTextField' " ...basically swift does not recognize reminderCells[ ] as a custom cell type (FilterTableViewCell or FilterTableViewCell2, both  have a "valueTextField" property and both are subclasses of UITableViewCell) ....it treats reminderCells[ ] as a baseclass type...

Comment: Same issue. It looks elegant but you can't do it that way. The compiler needs to know _at runtime_ that this is a FilterTableViewCell or FilterTableViewCell2. You can't do it "elegantly" through a lookup into an array. The only thing those two types have in common is that they are UITableViewCells, and a UITableViewCell has no `valueTextField` property. You can see that by examining the inferred type of `reminderCells`. You could "solve" it by making FilterTableViewCell and FilterTableViewCell2 subclasses of some third cell type that _does_ have a `valueTextField`, but you have not done that.

Comment: hmm then how come when i make all the items in reminderCells of the *same* type...for example when i  make all the items FilterTableViewCell() objects, i dont get any errors. how come swift only freaks out when reminderCells has a mix of FilterTableViewCell() and FilterTableViewCell2() objects?

Comment: Exactly as I already said, when you do the latter, Swift automatically infers that this is an array of UITableViewCell objects, which _doesn't_ have those properties. But when you do the former, Swift infers that this is an array of FilterTableViewCell, which _does_ have those properties. That is why the solution of having a common superclass that _does_ have those properties would work to quell the compiler's worries. Basically you just need to read my previous comment again.

Comment: Or of course you could make FilterTableViewCell the superclass of FilterTableViewCell2 (or vice versa) and thus do it with just two types.

Comment: thanks bro. I went with your second option and i think i've eliminated the issue....i upvoted your posts but it doesnt show because i'm new here...lol i just caught your edit...yeah i hate a lot of clutter and repetition in my code...but i'll take your advice

Comment: I was looking for that. thanks bro. i accepted your answer.